# Installing Phablet-Tools

Tags: ubuntu-touch

When I try to run in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

It gives the response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package phablet-tools
```

Comment: Ensure the [universe archive is enabled](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine#Adding_the_Universe_and_Multiverse_Repositories).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and than you can try install packages again.

Comment: Danke! Sorry, I'm new to this. Also sorry if my english is hard to understand. :)

Comment: not working for me

Comment: The version in the archive is always stale, and not maintained. always grab from the ppa, as mhall119 recommends

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the phablet PPA in order to get phablet-tools:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
$ sudo apt-get update
```

And then install the phablet-tools:

```
$ sudo apt-get install phablet-tools
```

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install for the full instructions

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure the [universe archive is enabled](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine#Adding_the_Universe_and_Multiverse_Repositories). You can do this by appending "universe" to the lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` which contain " trusty " and " trusty-updates "
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install phablet-tools`

Answer (score 2):

I am struggling with this myself - Note that there is a no-longer (in 2016) updated version of the phablet-tools package in trusty/universe. Use the PPA instead.; you need to download them from here; https://launchpad.net/~phablet-team/+archive/ubuntu/tools/+sourcepub/5673076/+listing-archive-extra - The trouble is I do not know where you should extract them to......

**UPDATE**

I spent lots of time trying to make this work; in the end I gave up - got an old machine, installed **precise** (which has Phablet-tools etc in its universe repository) - **or does it?** - I am still struggling with the phone installation

**Update 2**

Still struggling with this; The instruction page here  https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/ says *Note that there is a no-longer updated version of the **phablet-tools** package in **trusty/universe**. Please use the PPA instead.*

So I installed Precise on an old machine

however; [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/phablet-tools) it says phablet-tools for **precise** have been deleted.

It seems whatever I do I cannot achieve this. I will keep digging and post an update.

I could do with a plan B because this is driving me nuts...

**UPDATE 3**

Went back to try with Trusty; in trying to install phablet-tools as suggested above I get

`The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ubuntu-device-flash : Depends: click-ubuntu-policy but it is not installable
                       Depends: ubuntu-snappy-cli but it is not installable`
`