# Couldn't find package phablet-tools

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-touch

I am trying to install Ubuntu Touch on my Galaxy Nexus from 32-bit Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (not sure if that may be a possible reason) and after adding the repository I seem to get stuck installing the actual packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package phablet-tools
```

I poked around a little on google and on here trying to find a solution, it seemed like the idea of an apt-get upgrade worked for somebody else but it has failed for me (forum post can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282162/installing-phablet-tools).

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: 10.04 has reached end of life, you need to upgrade.

Comment: @psusi: 10.04 may be end of life on the desktop, but that isn't the reason why it isn't working here: there are non-EoL distros for which the phablet-tools package is not available.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge, if it still applies to a non EOL release and the question is edited to reference that instead, it can be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Those packages come from the [`phablet-team/tools` PPA](https://launchpad.net/~phablet-team/+archive/tools). As described in the [install instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install), that PPA contains "tools and dependencies to support Precise, Quantal, and Raring".

So you will need to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu to use the packages found in that PPA.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for getting back to me.